# kendo input textbox not setting the readonly property to true false dynamically

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am trying to make a set kendotextbox control on my angular form to readonly true/false based on toggling of a button. For some reason the textboxes dont seem to set to readonly false and is true all the time. Is there anything wrong with my implementation

```
<div class="col-md-3">
                    <input *ngIf="!EditMode" kendoTextBox readonly="true" class="form-control"
                        [(ngModel)]="ManagerDetails.Person.FIRST_NAME" />
                    <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox readonly="false" class="form-control"
                        [(ngModel)]="ManagerDetails.Person.FIRST_NAME" />   
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you share the inspected output html from the browser? I suspect the kendoTextBox may be doing it's own thing with inputs and wrapper tags

Comment: When i click edit the following is shown when i inspect the element <input _ngcontent-c7="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-touched" kendotextbox="" readonly="false">

Comment: looks to me right but then why am i not able to edit ?

Comment: I defer to the answer from @ConnorsFan

Answer (score 1):

Use the [brackets](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#remember-the-brackets) to make sure that Angular evaluates the boolean expression:

```
<input ... [readonly]="false" >
```

Without the brackets, the value is bound as the string `"false"`, which is a truthy value.

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-swd9mp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.